# Requirement already satisfied: cython

Tags: python

i want install cython and when install with pip return to me this error:

> **Requirement already satisfied: cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages**

my pip version is pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5 and python version is Python 3.5.2

Comment: `pip` or `pip3`?

Comment: Looks like you already have cython.

Comment: Not every terminal message is an error... :/

Comment: If you want this to be a valid question, you should demonstrate in its text that cython is not already usable, showing what you've tried and how it fails. (Be sure that the python install for which you can't use cython is the same one using `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` -- if the install associated with your `pip` executable is different from the one you're trying to use cython in, well, there's your problem).

Answer (score 0):

Then Cython is already installed. Go to your Python interpreter and type `import cython` and if there is no error you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that your Cython was not installed with the compiler callable from CLI(terminal). I found it a solution to deinstall the existing version and install it fresh:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall Cython
sudo pip3 install Cython
```